# Most pythonic way to check if a 1-dimensional list is an element of a 2-dimensional list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7.6, I have a list of rgb colors, each themselves a list, ie.:

```
color_list = [ [0, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0]....[255, 255, 255] ]
```

Calling this:

```
color = [0, 0, 0]

if color in color_list:
    # do stuff
```

Elicits:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I'm concerned that doing what the error suggests, ie. `color.any()` or `color.all()` is literally going to go looking for those integers anywhere in my color list. I can think up ways to achieve my actual aims, but my intuition is that Python has well-seen this need coming and there's a Pythonic way to achieve it. Lil' help?

## UPDATE

I'm fail. `color` in the above code was a `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: either `color` is a numpy array, or `color_list` is, or `color_list` is a list of numpy arrays. If all were lists, your code would have worked.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with python 2.7.6

Comment: Did not notice I was getting a numpy. ndarray back—thanks. /facepalm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you're seeing is coming from `numpy`.

This means that either `color` is a numpy array, or `color_list` is, or `color_list` is a list of numpy arrays. If all were lists, your code would have worked.

```
color_list = [ [0, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255] ]
color = [0, 0, 0]
color in color_list
=> True
```